# Replacing reactnative Stack.navigator Topbar

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ui-kitten

So I wanted to replace the stack.navigator top bar with KittenUi top navigation component. Im not a mobile developer but my company is to cheap to hire one. I'm using react-native expo.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by using option on stack.navigator

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={({ navigation }) => ({
  header: ({}) => {
    return (
      <TopNavigationAccessoriesShowcase navigation={navigation} />
    );
  },
})}
>
```